How to prevent ubuntu (22.04) from trying to auto connect to any new wifi network it detects?
How to prevent ubuntu (22.04) from trying to auto connect to any new wifi network it detects?
I turned on the wifi, just to find out it trying to connect to a neighbor wifi network... Quite strange as it looked like the network has a password set and it was empty. Because it shown as connected but I never put any password on it, and it was empty on the configurations.
So, what I need is to ubuntu stop doing this unsafe behavior of trying to connect anywhere it wants by default. It detects a new wifi and if it can it connects? I disagree with that... I want to be sure it is connecting to something that I think is ok, not to anything it wants...
So, how to change that default?
How to stop ubuntu from trying to connect to anything new it finds?
How to make that "connect automatically with priority" = 0, to be unchecked by default to any new wifi it detects?
This is not what I am asking: Disable WiFi auto-connect on Ubuntu Linux, this is after the connection happens. I want to prevent it from even trying to connect like crazy anywhere.

This looks like a security risk, and I am surprised there is so few to find about it. Similar topics don't take unprotected open wifis into account. Like this old thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/154880/how-to-disable-enable-automatically-connecting-to-wifi . But back than, too, all answers seem to relate to networks that you are already connected to (automatically).

it shown as connected to my neighbor wifi with a padlock icon (passworded). As I remember, I was unable to browse the internet tho, that's why I went to check what was wrong. So my guesses became: Or he hacked his wifi to look like my wifi and let me connect on it (but I dont have that much knowledge to be sure); or ubuntu bugged and shown it wrong; or he left his wifi w/o password until I connect on it, and then he put a password, so the padlock would show up; I dont know much about that stuff so my priority was just to disconnect everything as soon I could, instead of testing things.
